# react material - ui text field validation : set custom error messages

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-UI textfield, after I key in some value, I want to set a error message if custom validations fail.

I am able to set in error message when blank value is entered only. So instead of the blank value error messages, I want to add in my own customer error messages.

```
const checkValue = (newValue) => {
    var other = { 'a': 1 };
    if(!_.isEqual(newValue, other)) {
        alert('value is correct.');
        //I want to set error message next to field value is not correct.
    }
}

<TextField
    id="form-value"
    className={classes.textField}
    margin="dense"
    label={'value'}
    value={value}
    onKeyUp={e => { checkValue(e.target.value); }}
    onChange={e => { checkValue(e.target.value); }}
    variant="outlined"
    error={value=== ""}
    helperText={value=== "" ? 'Please enter a value!' : ' '}
    fullWidth
>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Paper` element under `TextField` with a value for it in the state that you set the error into when the criteria are satisfied in your `checkValue` method?

Comment: currently i can set in a blank value error message using helper text, i want to set the value after my validation method is triggered

Comment: If you use the `Paper` component for the error instead of `helperText`, you can fully control what you put inside it using your `checkValue` method. You can then use CSS to position it correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `helperText` prop to set your error message:

```
export default function TextFields() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    name: ""
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const error = values.name !== "a";

  return (
    <form>
      <TextField
        id="standard-name"
        label="Name"
        value={values.name}
        onChange={handleChange("name")}
        margin="normal"
        helperText={error ? "Name needs to be 'a'" : "Perfect!"}
        error={error}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here's an example in Code Sandbox

[image: Edit Material demo]

Answer (score 0):

Normally in helperText you call a function:

```
 helperfn() {    

               if (this.state.data.name.trim().length==0) return 'Can not be empty';
               if (this.state.data.name.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]/g, '').length>0) return 'Only letters and numbers';
             }
```