# how to disable future time in material-ui KeyboardDateTimePicker in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm using Material UI KeyboardDateTimePicker and by using disabledFuture I was able to disable future date but **I want to disable future time** as well. any solution would be appreciated

```
import { KeyboardDateTimePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
 <KeyboardDateTimePicker
            color="primary"
            disableFuture
            format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
            label={intl.formatMessage({ id: "end" })}
            margin="normal"
            onChange={(x) => onChange({ from, to: x?.toJSDate() ?? null })} 
            value={to}
            variant="inline"
            maxDate={new Date()}
          />
```

> Note - i don't want to update library

Comment: Currently, you can't do that.

Comment: You can use the onChange handler callback to filter and disable the changes if the time is a future time.

Comment: As he mention in question, he might want to disable the selection of time same as like the date. onChange he will show the error when future time is selected

Comment: as Gabriel Nuñez de Andrade said you cannot do this because the time component is generic for all dates. Since you have disabled future dates, The only time you will be able to select the future time is current day. This can be validated when user selection is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the value yourself by passing down an `error` prop to the underlying `Textfield` component, if the dateTime is in the future.

```js
<KeyboardDateTimePicker
  value={to}
  error={dateTimeIsInFuture(to)}
```

You can then add a custom error message using the `helperText` prop: [react material - ui text field validation : set custom error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903411/react-material-ui-text-field-validation-set-custom-error-messages).